# Storing value of

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, radio-button

The code below represents two sets of radio buttons. Whenever users click one button in each set, they'll be transported to a new page with the exact same set of radio buttons on that new page. But whenever they navigate to a new page or refresh the page, the latest state of radio buttons is lost. Is there a method which we can store the latest value for each set of radio buttons and display those latest values whenever we navigate to a new page or when the page is refreshed?
I've attempted to use defaultChecked but this method only seems to render initially.
Thanks in advance!

````
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function DisplayHomeOptions() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({ location: "", selector: "" })


    function handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value, type, checked } = event.target
        setFormData(prevFormData => {
            return {
                ...prevFormData,
                [name]: type === "checkbox" ? checked : value
            }
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const { location, selector } = formData;
        if (location && selector) {
            const target = navTarget[location][selector];
            if (target) {
                navigate(target);
            }
        }
    }, [formData]);

    const navTarget = {

        National: {
            Messages: "/national/messages",
            Polls: "/national/polls",
            Questions: "/national/questions",
        },
        Global: {
            Messages: "/global/messages",
            Polls: "/global/polls",
            Questions: "/global/questions",
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Option #1</legend>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="location"
                    value="Global"
                    onChange={handleChange}

                />

                <label htmlFor="Global">Global</label>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="location"
                    value="National"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="National">National</label>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Option #2</legend>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="selector"
                    value="Messages"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    
                />
                <label htmlFor="Messages">Messages</label>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="selector"
                    value="Questions"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="Questions">Questions</label>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="selector"
                    value="Polls"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="Polls">Polls</label>
            </fieldset>

        </div>
    )
}```
````

Comment: There are any number of state management tools that can help . React context is built-in, Redux (though that be too much for your needs), maybe Recoil.

Comment: When a new page is loaded, the information on the page is fresh. If you want the information from the forms to persist, you either need to cache it on the client side (using `localStorage` or a more organised system) or on the server side (in a database or an in-memory solution such as redis which is made available to the browser via an API).

Comment: I second using "app state" by either [Lifting the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a common ancestor to be shared to children, or by abstraction, a React context. It's common to also persist and initialize your app state to/from localStorage.